# assign HTTPS to node.js socket.io

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, socket.io

i want to create HTTPS server to my node.js socket.io server,
did it with self sign certification, using this code

```
    var fs = require( 'fs' );
var app = require('express')();
var https        = require('https');
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('C:/ssl/ia.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/ssl/ia.crt'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);
server.listen(8888);
```

but when purchasing real one i only get .crt file, how to secure my node app using it on windows server?

Comment: You should have created the key when you generated the CSR.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318997/convert-crt-file-to-cer-and-key

Comment: @Matt it didnt work

Comment: @Thabung i must use real SSL, self generated certificate will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, i had to do a CSR from my server using OPENSSL batch, in that case it will create CSR and the private KEY, buying SSL using the CSR will give me the CRT
and i will use the generated key from the OPENSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no private key - no way.

You need a private key that was used to purchase the certificate.

Or you can use `letsencrypt-express`:

> Free SSL and managed or automatic HTTPS for node.js with Express, Koa,
>   Connect, Hapi, and all other middleware systems.
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/letsencrypt-express

Comment: is there's a way to generate or get the private key from the purchased SSL ?  already asked tech support of couple of websites selling SSL's and they cant give me private key, this is my big issue